# Jquery display "yes" when a file has been uploaded from an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I would like to display in a "yes" id if a file was loaded into an input type file (Warning when the file is selected it is automatically saved without clicking send)

My input

```
<div class="customizationUploadBrowseImg">
    <input type="file" name="file{$field.id_customization_field}" id="img{$customizationField}"
     class="file_upload form-control customization_block_input {if isset($pictures.$key)}filled{/if}"/>
</div>
```

The id or message must appear

```
<li>
    <strong>- Couverture personnalisée :</strong> <span id="is_covert_show"></span>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you are working on a jQuery/Javascript solution, can you post your current code please so we can see what the issue might be?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code using the `<>` snippet editor in a [mcve]

Comment: `<input type=file onchange=something(this.files[0])>`